# JQuery news ticker but with scrolling text

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-plugins

**Question Updated:**
I am using this news ticker plugin to display the content in a list. Unfortunately the animation  uses some sort of typing animation when I need it to just fade-in and out.

How would I change the animation used in the Fiddle example to fade-in/out without the typing animation?

Hope someone can help.

**JSFiddle updated with Controls:**

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/bleachie/AvFMZ/5/

Thanks.

Comment: How would I change the animation used in the Fiddle example to match the marquee example?

Comment: I wouldn't, because that's annoying as hell.

Comment: Why not just switch plugins? That one specifically mentions "BBC Style"

Comment: Why can't you use remysharp.com one that you have mentioned in your question. http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/ link has the configurations and downloading facility. Try it out

Comment: Marquee doesn't have next and prev controls like the BBC Style plugin.

Comment: OK, how about just making it fade-in? :)